# Issue Running PI example on Standalone Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, mobius

First let me say that I am **newbie** to Spark, SparkR, Hadoop, etc...  I am .NET developer that has been tasked with integrating our .NET applications with Apache Spark and eventually Apache SparkR.  I am currently able to run the samples locally, but when pointing to my Linux Cluster (Master: spark01, slaves: spark02-spark05), I am unable to run the PI sample.  When I use the following script, I get the following errors.

```
My Client Mode Command:
<p>
C:\MyData\Apache_Spark\SparkCLR-master\build\runtime>scripts\sparkclr-submit.cmd --proxy-user miadmin --total-executor-cores 2 --master spark://spark01:7077 --exe Pi.exe C:\MyData\Apache_Spark\SparkCLR-master\examples\pi\bin\Debug spark.local.dir %temp%
```

#### Errors:

```
"C:\MyData\Apache_Spark\SparkCLR-master\build\tools\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\conf\spark-env.cmd"
SPARKCLR_JAR=spark-clr_2.10-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Zip driver directory C:\MyData\Apache_Spark\SparkCLR-master\examples\pi\bin\Debug to C:\Users\shunley\AppData\Local\Temp\Debug_1453925538545.zip
[sparkclr-submit.cmd] Command to run --proxy-user miadmin --total-executor-cores 2 --master spark://spark01:7077 --name Pi --files C:\Users\shunley\AppData\Local\Temp\Debug_1453925538545.zip --class org.apache.spark.deploy.csharp.CSharpRunner C:\MyData\Apache_Spark\SparkCLR-master\build\runtime\lib\spark-clr_2.10-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar C:\MyData\Apache_Spark\SparkCLR-master\examples\pi\bin\Debug C:\MyData\Apache_Spark\SparkCLR-master\examples\pi\bin\Debug\Pi.exe spark.local.dir C:\Users\shunley\AppData\Local\Temp
[CSharpRunner.main] Starting CSharpBackend!
[CSharpRunner.main] Port number used by CSharpBackend is 4485
[CSharpRunner.main] adding key=spark.jars and value=file:/C:/MyData/Apache_Spark/SparkCLR-master/build/runtime/lib/spark-clr_2.10-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to environment
[CSharpRunner.main] adding key=spark.app.name and value=Pi to environment
[CSharpRunner.main] adding key=spark.cores.max and value=2 to environment
[CSharpRunner.main] adding key=spark.files and value=file:/C:/Users/shunley/AppData/Local/Temp/Debug_1453925538545.zip to environment
[CSharpRunner.main] adding key=spark.submit.deployMode and value=client to environment
[CSharpRunner.main] adding key=spark.master and value=spark://spark01:7077 to environment
[2016-01-27T20:12:19.7218665Z] [SHUNLEY10] [Info] [ConfigurationService] ConfigurationService runMode is CLUSTER
[2016-01-27T20:12:19.7228674Z] [SHUNLEY10] [Info] [SparkCLRConfiguration] CSharpBackend successfully read from environment variable CSHARPBACKEND_PORT
[2016-01-27T20:12:19.7228674Z] [SHUNLEY10] [Info] [SparkCLRIpcProxy] CSharpBackend port number to be used in JvMBridge is 4485
[2016-01-27 15:12:19,866] [1] [DEBUG] [Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Examples.PiExample] - spark.local.dir is set to C:\Users\shunley\AppData\Local\Temp\
[2016-01-27 15:12:21,467] [1] [INFO ] [Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Examples.PiExample] - ----- Running Pi example -----
collectAndServe on object of type NullObject failed
null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.api.csharp.CSharpBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(CSharpBackendHandler.scala:153)
at org.apache.spark.api.csharp.CSharpBackendHandler.channelRead0(CSharpBackendHandler.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.api.csharp.CSharpBackendHandler.channelRead0(CSharpBackendHandler.scala:27)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 9, spark02): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "CSharpWorker.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.api.csharp.CSharpRDD.compute(CSharpRDD.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:187)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 15 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "CSharpWorker.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.api.csharp.CSharpRDD.compute(CSharpRDD.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:187)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 15 more
()
methods:
public static int org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
args:
argType: org.apache.spark.api.csharp.CSharpRDD, argValue: CSharpRDD[1] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43
[2016-01-27T20:12:28.0995397Z] [SHUNLEY10] [Error] [JvmBridge] JVM method execution failed: Static method collectAndServe failed for class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD when called with 1 parameters ([Index=1, Type=JvmObjectReference, Value=12], )
[2016-01-27T20:12:28.0995397Z] [SHUNLEY10] [Error] [JvmBridge] org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 9, spark02): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "CSharpWorker.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.api.csharp.CSharpRDD.compute(CSharpRDD.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:187)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 15 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.api.csharp.CSharpBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(CSharpBackendHandler.scala:153)
at org.apache.spark.api.csharp.CSharpBackendHandler.channelRead0(CSharpBackendHandler.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.api.csharp.CSharpBackendHandler.channelRead0(CSharpBackendHandler.scala:27)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "CSharpWorker.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.api.csharp.CSharpRDD.compute(CSharpRDD.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:187)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 15 more

[2016-01-27T20:12:28.1296129Z] [SHUNLEY10] [Exception] [JvmBridge] JVM method execution failed: Static method collectAndServe failed for class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD when called with 1 parameters ([Index=1, Type=JvmObjectReference, Value=12], )
at Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallJavaMethod(Boolean isStatic, Object classNameOrJvmObjectReference, String methodName, Object[] parameters)
[2016-01-27 15:12:28,130] [1] [INFO ] [Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Examples.PiExample] - ----- Error running Pi example (duration=00:00:06.6599877) -----
System.Exception: JVM method execution failed: Static method collectAndServe failed for class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD when called with 1 parameters ([Index=1, Type=JvmObjectReference, Value=12], )
at Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallJavaMethod(Boolean isStatic, Object classNameOrJvmObjectReference, String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallStaticJavaMethod(String className, String methodName, Object[] parameters)
at Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Proxy.Ipc.RDDIpcProxy.CollectAndServe()
at Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Core.RDD1.Collect() at Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Core.RDD1.Reduce(Func`3 f)
at Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Examples.PiExample.Pi() in C:\MyData\Apache_Spark\SparkCLR-master\examples\Pi\Program.cs:line 76
at Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Examples.PiExample.Main(String[] args) in C:\MyData\Apache_Spark\SparkCLR-master\examples\Pi\Program.cs:line 35
[2016-01-27 15:12:28,131] [1] [INFO ] [Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Examples.PiExample] - Completed running examples. Calling SparkContext.Stop() to tear down ...
[2016-01-27 15:12:28,131] [1] [INFO ] [Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Examples.PiExample] - If this program (SparkCLRExamples.exe) does not terminate in 10 seconds, please manually terminate java process launched by this program!!!
Requesting to close all call back sockets.
[CSharpRunner.main] closing CSharpBackend
Requesting to close all call back sockets.
[CSharpRunner.main] Return CSharpBackend code 1
Utils.exit() with status: 1, maxDelayMillis: 1000
```

I have a couple of questions as the documentation and the quickstart here: https://github.com/Microsoft/SparkCLR/wiki/Quick-Start , didn't really talk about it.

When the Quickstart says to use the following command for a standalone cluster environment:

```
cd \path\to\runtime

scripts\sparkclr-submit.cmd ^
--total-executor-cores 2 ^
--master spark://host:port ^ 
--exe Pi.exe ^
\path\to\Pi\bin[debug|release] ^
spark.local.dir %temp%
```

I understand the navigating to the runtime folder (locally or on the submitting server) on the first line. I get specifying the master so it knows which spark cluster to run on (this is the remote spark cluster). Now, what is confusing here is are we still pointing to the local (windows) file system for the Pi executable and the temp directory?  Could we also specify a data directory?  If we're specifying the linux directory on the cluster for our data, what's the format (especially if we're not using Hadoop)?  user@spark url:/path/to/sparkclr/runtime/samples/Pi/bin?

We're currently looking to use Spark and SparkR to do our processing from our application and I am just trying to understand how your API interacts with Spark, submitting work, retrieving results, etc..

Any help getting the Cluster Samples up and running (Client and Cluster mode) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the given error message, it seems CSharpWorker.exe is missing. Please double check whether it is present under directory C:\MyData\Apache_Spark\SparkCLR-master\examples\pi\bin\Debug.

Below is a typical file list of Pi example FYI:

```
01/25/2016  02:36 PM    <DIR>          .
01/25/2016  02:36 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/21/2016  11:58 AM            16,384 CSharpWorker.exe
01/21/2016  11:58 AM             1,737 CSharpWorker.exe.config
01/13/2016  09:55 PM           304,640 log4net.dll
01/13/2016  09:55 PM         1,533,153 log4net.xml
01/21/2016  11:58 AM           233,472 Microsoft.Spark.CSharp.Adapter.dll
01/13/2016  09:55 PM           520,192 Newtonsoft.Json.dll
01/13/2016  09:55 PM           501,178 Newtonsoft.Json.xml
01/21/2016  12:42 PM             8,704 Pi.exe
01/13/2016  10:00 PM             1,673 Pi.exe.config
01/21/2016  12:42 PM            17,920 Pi.pdb
01/25/2016  02:36 PM            24,216 Pi.vshost.exe
01/13/2016  10:00 PM             1,673 Pi.vshost.exe.config
07/10/2015  07:01 PM               490 Pi.vshost.exe.manifest
01/13/2016  09:55 PM            74,240 Razorvine.Pyrolite.dll
01/13/2016  09:55 PM            40,960 Razorvine.Serpent.dll
```

Answers to your other questions:

Question 1: what is confusing here is are we still pointing to the local (windows) file system for the Pi executable and the temp directory?

It depends on which deploy mode you use. For client mode, as driver program runs locally, you should need to put Pi executable and its dependencies on a local file system. 
For cluster mode, you need to put the executable and dependencies into a zip file and upload it to HDFS, also need to put spark-clr_2.10-1.5.200.jar on HDFS, then use below command to submit the application.

```
sparkclr-submit.cmd --proxy-user miadmin --total-executor-cores 20 --master spark://spark01:7077 --remote-sparkclr-jar hdfs://path/to/spark-clr_2.10-1.5.200.jar --exe Pi.exe hdfs://path/to/Pi.zip
```

Question 2: Could we also specify a data directory? If we're specifying the linux directory on the cluster for our data, what's the format (especially if we're not using Hadoop)? user@spark url:/path/to/sparkclr/runtime/samples/Pi/bin

If I don't misunderstand, the data directory you mentioned here should be used by your driver program. If so, it's totally determined by whether your driver can handle the format. All the arguments which are specified after driver directory or zip in the submission cmd will be passed to driver program directly as program arguments.